# Parameterized R Markdown document creation

Tags: r, r-markdown, tidyverse

I am having trouble rendering a markdown file from each row in a tibble. I've created a very simple example of what I think should work but when I run the following code I get the error:

```
Error in `pmap()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
```

This based on the example in the https://r4ds.had.co.nz/r-markdown.html#parameters book.

I would think that it would at least be able to read in the passed in parameter but that isn't the case.

`ReportGenTest.R`

```
# Report Gen Test
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
df.data <- tribble(
  ~EmplId, ~Name, ~Gender,
  "146193", "Tony","M",
  "146194", "Bob","M",
  "146195", "Sarah","F"

)

df.report <- df.data |>
  mutate(output_file = stringr::str_c('Report_', EmplId, '_', Name, '.pdf'),
         params = map(EmplId, ~list(my_emplid = .))) %>%
  select (output_file, params)



df.report %>%
#  select(output_file, params) %>%
  purrr::pwalk(rmarkdown::render,
               input = "ReportGenTest.Rmd")
```

`ReportGenTest.Rmd`

````
---
title: "ReportGenTest"
author: "Tony Jones"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
params:
  my_emplid: "146193"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}

# library(tidyverse)
 knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
# 
# e % 
#   filter(EmplId == params$my_emplid)

```

# Hi `r params$my_emplid`
````

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was using a .pdf file as the `output_file` name but `output` as `html_document` in the yaml header. Once I changed the yaml header from

```
output:
  html_document
```

to

```
output:
  pdf_document
```

it started to work.